# JMeter is not recording requests of android based app runs over HTTP

Tags: android, jmeter, performance-testing

I have to load test an android based mobile app using JMeter which runs over http. But JMeter is not capturing the request. While I saw that there is no problem in connection between the phone and JMeter because other apps's requests are captured successfully. I am using JMeter version 2.13.
While at the time of recording the app is running in phone which means it has no problem with stetted proxy. I also used the mobile recorder provided by Blazemeter to record over the cloud but again apart from testing app other app's request captured.Please suggest the workaround to record.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler or Charles to observe the network traffic of your app ? That should be first point of troubleshooting.

Comment: Yeah , I tried with Fiddler as well but this tool is also not responding for the app. I got to know this android app is built on xamarin framework , is this the blocker? If yes then please suggest the workaround.

Comment: a quick google search shows that monitoring xamarin based apps traffic will be an issue. Please refer to following links .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678178/why-doesnt-traffic-using-xamarins-monotouch-implementation-of-mobileservicecli

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11992/why-cant-fiddler-detect-traffic-from-xamarin-apps