# RestSharp portable RestClient Proxy property is not working

Tags: c#, proxy, xamarin, restsharp

Here is what is the issue. I'm using portable RestSharp which uses HttpClient under the hood. But for iOS there is problem with HttpClient, because the Default IWebProxy instance doesn't allow to monitor requests using request monitoring software like Charles ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492126/http-traffic-monitoring-issue-when-using-monotouch-httpclient-and-charles-proxy) to see the issue and the solution )
The solution for this is using `CFNetwork.GetDefaultProxy ()` which returns `IWebProxy` and set it as proxy of a request. I tried setting the Proxy property of `RestClient` but it didn't work, when digging in the open source code of portable `RestClient` I found out that the Proxy property is not used anywhere. The only place where it is used is commented out. That method is called `ConfigureProxy` line 572 in `RestSharp.Portable` project `RestClient` file, and this method is called only from `ConfigureHttp` method line 541 same file, which is also commented out. I believe this is a bug. May be someone has forgotten to set Proxy after commenting out this code. So can someone tell me wether it will be safe to remove the commented line, or may be say the right place where to set the proxy of IHttp interface? For instance is it safe to set the proxy on the line 393 (this is again in the RestClient file) of the attached image, like

```
httpRequest.Proxy = this.Proxy;
```

[image]

**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by myself after 2 days of debugging RestSharp.Portable 3.1.0 source code.

There is a bug in 
`RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient.Shared` - project
`DefaultHttpClientFactory` - class
`CreateMessageHandler` - method

Original code is:

```
if (handler.SupportsProxy && _proxyProperty != null && proxy != null)
{
    _proxyProperty.SetValue(handler, new RequestProxyWrapper(proxy), null);
}
```

Code does not work because `_proxyProperty` is null. This field initializes within constructor by reflection.

```
_proxyProperty = typeof(HttpClientHandler).GetProperty("Proxy");
```

Simulator initializes this property well, but real iOS device doesn't. I do not know why it happens.

So, here is the code that contains the fix:

```
if (handler.SupportsProxy && proxy != null)
{
    handler.Proxy = new RequestProxyWrapper(proxy);
}
```

I have added this fix into my application using reflection. If you want to do the same you should wrap your authenticator(s) or implement dummy one and override two methods:

```
public override bool CanPreAuthenticate(IHttpClient client, IHttpRequestMessage request, ICredentials credentials)
{
    return true;
}
```

and

```
public override async Task PreAuthenticate(IHttpClient client, IHttpRequestMessage request, ICredentials credentials)
{
...
    // get private "handler" field of type DefaultHttpClient from client by reflection here
    // get private "proxy" field of type IWebProxy from "handler" by reflection here
    // set private "proxy" field if it's null by reflection here
...
}
```

Hope this help. Do not forget to test your solution on each platform:)


I have added new issue on [github FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/issues/57)

Comment: In fact, this code with the proxy property reflection was meant as a workaround for Xamarin, because even though the proxy property should be available, it throws an exception when you want to use it. I'll provide an update that tries to use the field instead it no proxy was found.

Comment: I caught an exception which said that there was no setter for property Proxy too. I have no idea why it happens.
I guess your new workaround with private field will work OK.
Many thanks.

Comment: Fixed in 3.1.1 (please file an issue when the problem still exists)

Comment: The problem still exists. Please take a look at [my comment](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/commit/bf85d040863736c04df870459bfe4a911e3e8908#diff-a6263edfa474ac89c775f7930cb26a50R50)

Comment: Fixed in 3.1.3. Thanks to Mark