# Charles is not capturing HTTP requests from a Java client (client is based on spring rest template) in my MAC pro

Tags: http, proxy, fiddler, charles-proxy, webproxy

Environment: MAC Proc

I have looked at [HTTP Traffic monitoring issue when using MonoTouch, HttpClient and Charles Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492126/http-traffic-monitoring-issue-when-using-monotouch-httpclient-and-charles-proxy).

Although my question is similar to it, my application is using **RestTemplate** http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-android/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html. I am able to capture HTTP and HTTPS traffic whenever request is through web browsers (Safari and Chrome to be specific), whereas when I make rest requests **through my application (which is basically using RestTemplate) Charles proxy is not capturing them.**

From the answers to the above questions, it should be something related setting proxy setting on the RestTempate. But am a .NET developer and quite familiar with fiddler - but recently moved to Java and new to Charles - so it will be great if you can let me know specific details, or your thoughts on configuring rest template to use my mac os proxy...

Basically question is **how to configure my rest template (client) such that the charles web proxy is able to capture the requests** and responses through my application (client).

And rest template is instantiated by custom request factory which extends __https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/**SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory**.html.

---

Looks like I need to do something similar to this (reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-proxy)

```
<bean id="requestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="proxy">
        <bean id="proxy" class="java.net.Proxy">
            <constructor-arg>
                <util:constant static-field="java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP"/>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="java.net.InetSocketAddress">
                    <constructor-arg value="123.0.0.1"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="8080"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar problem. But I was using JUnit and core Java. Below is a link that helped in a few cases for me.

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/

you can go to JAVA APPLICATION PROXY CONFIGURATION to find the answer.

> You can configure your Java application to use Charles in code or as
>   command line arguments to the java executable.
>
> > System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
> >
> > System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
>
> And for HTTPS as well. Note that you may also want to configure Java
>   to trust Charles’s root certificate in this case (see SSL Proxying).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have added it as vm param as well. But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do that in tomcat level, you must config proxy in RestTemplate. Reference this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45188490/1743046, although it use HttpClient but I think you can find a same way for RestTemplate