# How to set proxy host on HttpClient request in Java

Tags: java, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I want to set proxy before sending `HttpClient` request on a URL. As I am able to connect it curl command setting up the proxy but with Java code I am not able to do that.

Curl command:

```
**curl -I -x IP:80  URL**
```

Code change done in java file:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
EntityEnclosingMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(requestXML, "text/xml", "utf-8"));
```

With above code changes in my java file I am getting below error :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Which shows that I am not able to connect that URL with the proxy I am trying to use to connect the URL.

Comment: Which shows that there was no HTTP proxy running at the host:port you specified for it.

Comment: @EJP i didn;t understand your question , yes proxy is not getting setup because of that we are getting connection refused error

Comment: Deleted my answer, as I got the question wrong.

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you talking about the Apache HttpClient?

Comment: Which version do you use? As for the newest version you should be able to use the example given here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java or here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e485

Comment: Apache Tomcat/6.0.24 and Java version: 1.7.0_141

Comment: 1107 search results for query `java http client proxy` 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this could be helpful:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
config.setProxy("someProxyURL", "someProxyPort");

Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope("someProxyURL", "someProxyPort");
client.getState().setProxyCredentials(authScope, credentials);

EntityEnclosingMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(requestXML, "text/xml", "utf-8"));
```

Comment: Which HttpClient version do you use? I can't even find the Class "HostConfiguration".

Comment: @刘同彬 3.1 I suppose. If you use 4.x version, look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955644/apache-httpclient-4-1-proxy-settings/4957144#4957144

Comment: What if I have a proxy without user and password?

Comment: @DontPanic are there some distinct signatures that would allow a server to detect the request to be from HttpClient?

Answer (score 8):

A full example is given in this tutorial: [How do I setting a proxy for HttpClient?](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-setting-a-proxy-for-httpclient/)

```
package org.kodejava.example.commons.httpclient;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HttpGetProxy {
    private static final String PROXY_HOST = "proxy.host.com";
    private static final int PROXY_PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("https://kodejava.org");

        HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
        config.setProxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

        String username = "guest";
        String password = "s3cr3t";
        Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
        AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

        client.getState().setProxyCredentials(authScope, credentials);

        try {
            client.executeMethod(method);

            if (method.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
                System.out.println("Response = " + response);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

For this, you **need to add a jar file**: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar

**Complete Example of a Apache HttpClient 4.1, setting proxy can be found below**

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("ip address",port number);
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);

HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param name", param));
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.ISO_8859_1));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println("Request Handled?: " + response.getStatusLine());
InputStream in = entity.getContent();
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

**Resource Link:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957144

For other version like 4.3 or 4.3+, you can go through this SO answer: [Apache HttpClient 4.1 - Proxy Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962047/apache-httpclient-4-1-proxy-authentication)

Answer (score 7):

Add maven dependency (4.2.X+):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Use `HttpClientBuilder` and set flag `useSystemProperties`:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
```

then you have two options at least:

Option A: Override arguments, i.e.

```
java -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true 
     -Dhttp.proxyHost=PROXY_HOST
     -Dhttp.proxyPort=PROXY_PORT 
     -Dhttp.proxyUser=USERNAME
     -Dhttp.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
     -jar your-app.jar
```

Option B: Set up JVM (`${JAVA_HOME}/lib/net.properties`):

```
java.net.useSystemProxies=true
http.proxyHost=some-host
http.proxyPort=some-port
```

and run your application

Comment: `java.net.useSystemProxies` means that the OS proxy setting will be used. What is the actual behaviour if you mix it with explicit proxy settings like `http.proxyHost`? I think it has no effect then.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 17 it works like this:

```
HttpClient.newBuilder().proxy(ProxySelector.of(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("proxy.host.de", 3126))).build();
```

(3126 is the proxy port in my code snippet.)

Answer (score 1):

System properties usually have to be set right upfront, which means either in the jvm startup with
`-Dhttp.proxyHost=some.host.com`
`-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`, not forgetting the httpsProxyHost and ...Port)

Or which should work, too, in a static {} block.

I personally find the Jersey client implementation easier to work with, if you have the option to switch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following to achieve the same tasks of having a proxy:

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
        post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

 String PROXY_HOST = "proxy.abc.com";
        int PROXY_PORT = 8080;
        HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
        config.setProxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

int statusCode = client.executeMethod(post);
logger.debug("Status Code for Proxy Request:" + statusCode);
```