# Java 11 HttpClient with proxy, header parser received no bytes

Tags: java

Trying to make a simple get request using `java.net.http.HttpClient`.
it works without the proxy usage. Proxy is valid and working. Proxy supports https/s and socks5 connections. However when i try to use the proxy as in the example, receiving this error:

```
 java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes
```

I think i pass proxy into the client correctly (as in example here https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/recipes.html ), although i pass the proxy IP, not the domain, which is seems to be accepted by `InetSocketAddress`.

example:

```
                HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                        .uri(new URI("http://google.com"))
                        .headers("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                        .GET()
                        .build();

                HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient
                        .newBuilder()
                        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
                        .proxy(ProxySelector.of(
                            new InetSocketAddress(
                                    "1.1.1.1", 1111
                            )
                        ))
                        .build()
                        .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Comment: could you also double check that you are actually hitting the proxy ? and whether the proxy responses back / get a response from google ?

Comment: i don't think i'm actually hitting the proxy and this `HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes` probably means that the client wasn't setup correctly -> proxy wasnt setup correctly

Comment: hmm take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821561/how-to-set-proxy-host-on-httpclient-request-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1), dont know if its using the latest `HttpClient`, but surely there must be a way getting the client conf. Also a second thought, because i am seeing some other questions, if you can trace the actual http response, in case it does not have a header, then the `HttpClient` fails to parse the response

Comment: thats answer uses apache's `HttpClient`, not `java.net.http`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I fixed it by setting the preferred protocol to HTTP 1.1.

```
HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .version(Version.HTTP_1_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that issue comes from a bug in the http client implementation in the JDK.

We can find JDK 15 was impacted: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8239117, but the ticket has not been closed or solved.

I confirm that forcing setting the version to http 1.1 fixed that issue.

Interestingly, no proxy is needed to hit this issue, only a badly implemented server.